# Why am I getting this error FutureWarning: Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

Why am I getting this error

> FutureWarning: Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead in jupyter?

What is wrong with my code?

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Comment: there's no error in you code, just a deprecation warning.

Comment: You probably updated your version of Pandas.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually nothing "wrong" with your code, as it says, the function deprecated, means its not advised to use it anymore.
Usually, deprecated functions have replacements, in your case `engine_kwargs` is the replacement for your function, try using it.